# Using qrcode reading without touch event in SmartEye Glass

Tags: android, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

We create an application with HelloWorld sample that scans QR codes and uses the database. But we want to do it without touch event. The current situation, we have to use touch event to scan QR code. Is it about HelloWorld sample or our application? How can we solve it? Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Why do you need to use touch event? Is it to trigger the scan? If so, you can program your application in a way that will continuously scan.

Comment: Yes now, we use touch event to trigger the scan. But how can we program our application to continuously scan? What do you suggest?

Comment: You need to take the part of the code you use to do QR scanning. Then you should run this for every image frame that you receive from the glasses.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem with using SamplaCameraExtension Sample. We moved all codes to SampleCameraExtension so now the program is running smoothly

Comment: Do you plan to put it in GitHub?

Comment: Hey I am currently trying the same using the SampleCameraExtension and zxing library to decode the bitmap, have u got it working? If yes can u provide an example maybe? Regards Chris